# How to prevent Windows 7 from creating system restore files and shadow copies?

Tags: windows-7, windows, disk-space, disk-cleanup

I have noticed that my Windows 7 partition loses free space about half a gigabyte every day until there is no space left anymore. I can work around this by going to Disk Cleanup -> More Options -> System Restore and Shadow Copies. But it will create all those files slowly again and I have to remove them frequently. Those files take around 10GB of space total in the end.

How can I stop my Windows 7 from creating these files and keep my disk clean?

I have so small partition that I cannot spare any gigabytes.

Comment: Have you tried turning off System Restore if you're so concerned about it?

Comment: You're welcome, but I'm surprised that wasn't the first thing you looked into doing instead of simply deleting the restore points repeatedly.

Comment: @Karan, didnt expect it to be that straight-forward :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Start > Run > SystemPropertiesProtection.exe`
2. [image: 1]
3. [image: 2]
4. Additionally you can disable the **Volume Shadow Copy (VSS)** services completely via `Start > Run > services.msc`, but if it's set to *Manual* it's best to leave it alone.

Comment: For the step 1 i used: Control Panel -> System -> System Protection ->

Comment: There are lots of ways to get there but I just mentioned the fastest one. Searching for "system" in the Start Menu and clicking on "View advanced system settings" is another one. All roads lead to Rome. :)

Comment: Yup, I wanted to add the path without exe, because i am afraid they will rename those exes in future versions... as they have done before.

Comment: Anything can change in future versions. Since the Control Panel is going away in Win10 the path you gave will also be outdated.